# AttributeError after sorting through elementtree values

Tags: python, sorting, elementtree

I'm trying to take elementtree elements picked from an XML and sort them through alphabetical order. Since there's multiple XMLs I'm sorting through (keys are defined in the `platforms` list), I'm first storing the values in a dictionary with the key and then sorting them.

I've tried the following:

```
titles = {}

for platform in platforms:
    for title in self.databases[platform][1].findall("game"):
        if title.find("locale", {"lang": "EN"}) is not None:
            titles[title.find("locale", {"lang": "EN"}).find("title").text + " - " + platform] = title
            print(title.find("region").text) # this works

for key, title in sorted(titles.items()):
    for s in title:
        t = s.find("region").text
```

However, I'm getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` with the last line of the code, which doesn't make sense because I'm able to print the XML value in the loop where I assign the values to a dictionary.

2 questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this? I'm sure that this can be optimized in a better way. Maybe elementtree or Python has a nice little function that can sort when the items are stored as elements?
2. Why am I getting an `AttributeError`? Is something breaking after I store them in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to question 2. Why the line "for s in title" (is title an iterator)?  While title.find(region) has a text attribute it is not clear that s.find("region")  does

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have been iterating through that. Now it works.